# Receive XMLHttp Body in node.js

Tags: node.js, web, xmlhttprequest

I have JavaScript code posting a XMLHttp Request to my Node.js application.

I managed to receive the request easily using express. However, I am not able to read the body of the POST request with bodyParser(). It just sais "undefined" or "{}" when accessing req.body.

How could I possibly do this?

Comment: Are you sure your request is a POST and not a GET request?

Comment: yes, it's a OPTIONS/POST request.

Comment: Can you check if your request body is really ok in devtools or firebug? Also, try to remove the bodyParser middleware and inspect the raw `req.body` that you're receiving.

Comment: the request is a 100% valid POST. I tried with php and it worked. when I dont use bodyParser, body is undefined.

Comment: Can you post an example of your body, as seen in devtools/firebug?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HXLyaALu this is what it looks like. it just keeps pending and I can not access "pic" in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for connect's `bodyParser` middleware in 1.x (or `multipart` middleware in 2.x) say

> As a security measure files are stored in a separate object, stored
>   as `req.files`. This prevents attacks that may potentially alter
>   filenames, and depending on the application gain access to restricted files.

Try

```
req.files.pic
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. Do you have the link to the documentation? I can't find it.

Comment: Yeah, the top-level connect site only links to docs for 2.x (http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html), but I was able to find the 1.x bodyParser docs here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html